# at command seems to be discarding output

Tags: debian, at

Running 'at' on either Debian Jessie or Raspbian Jessie, output seems to go down a black hole whatever I do. I'm wanting to capture errors, but even in the simple case of stdout I can't seem to capture output.

I'm trying, for example:

```
echo "curl 'http://www.example.com' > tmp.log" | at -M -t 201706042241.36
```

tmp.log is always empty, but the same `curl` not put through `at` produces the expected html. If I omit the -M I get nothing.

What I really want is the error output. If I try

```
echo "curl 'http://badbadbad.example.com' 2>&1 > tmp.log" | at -M -t 201706042241.36
```

I get an empty tmp.log; and if I omit -M I get an empty email. If I omit the redirects, thus:

```
echo "curl 'http://badbadbad.example.com'" | at -t 201706042241.36
```

I also get an empty email. I'd expect to see `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: badbadbad.example.com`

There's nothing in syslog, messages or daemon.log in /var/log. I'm running the commands as an ordinary user, not root.

`at` seems to hijack and discard every attempt to obtain the output from the command I'm running. Am I misunderstanding something about `at`?

Comment: Your first command produces the expected output for me. (Gentoo though.)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pipe `|` the *output* of your commands to `at` instead of giving it the *commands* to be run at the time specified. `at` reads the commands from the standard input (`at>` prompt) or from a file (`-f`). Synopsis:

```
at [-V] [-q queue] [-f file] [-mldbv] TIME
at [-V] [-q queue] [-f file] [-mldbv] -t time_arg
```

Here's a good [article with usage examples](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm).

Comment: No I'm not - I'm echo-ing the commands into `at`, which reads commands to be executed from stdin. The commands (`curl ...`) work, at the time requested, it's the capturing the output from them that's the problem.

Comment: My bad. I tested the last command and the result was as expected.